# How to start others application in Widgets click event?

Tags: android, widget

I designed a widget and successful using "setOnClickPendingIntent" to active the click event, but I want to start other application witch is install in my Android phone (such as Google Map), how can I using in this following command?

if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK)) {
   ....
}

Beside that, My widget is a clock widget, I want to click a button to start the "system clock page" and click the date to the system Calendar. How can I make it? many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to start other application

There is no such concept in Android. You can start an activity via `startActivity()`, if there is a documented and supported `Intent` you can use to get to the activity you wish.

> My widget is a clock widget, I want to
>   click a button to start the "system
>   clock page" and click the date to the
>   system Calendar.

There is no "system Calendar" in Android. There is a Google Calendar client that is part of the Android open source project and exists on some phones, but it is not part of the Android SDK.